# Am getting error (150) of foreign key constraint after executing this query

Tags: mysql

```
create table generate (
    ticket_id numeric(5),
    person_id numeric(5),
    primary key(ticket_id,person_id),
    foreign key(ticket_id) references ticket(ticket_id),
    foreign key(person_id) references person(person_id)
);
```

Comment: Can you include the other two tables?

Comment: What is the *full* text of the error?

Comment: CREATE TABLE person(person_id numeric (5) PRIMARY KEY,person_name varchar(20),phone numeric(10),email_id varchar(20),address varchar(20));

Comment: CREATE TABLE ticket(complaint_id  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,ticket_id numeric(5),type varchar(10),t_date date,description varchar(100),PRIMARY KEY(complaint_id,ticket_id));

Comment: #1005 - Can't create table `try`.`generate` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")